# C++ generic data structures - data field assignment-operator vs copy c'tor

Tags: c++, templates, generics, constructor, variable-assignment

Does using an assignment operator instead of copy c'tor in generic structures, considered as bad coding? Or it doesn't matter because perhaps it's widely assumed that if there is a special c'tor for a certain data type, there should be an appropriate assignment operator too?

For example if I'm making my own generic linked list, using 
template 
and DATA data; 
field inside each node. So the question is if in some place on my list code I can use assignment operator between two DATA variables.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example or two?

Comment: The assignment operator and the copy constructor do different things. They are not interchangeable at all. It's not a matter of being good or bad coding, it's mostly a matter of either one of them not doing the other's job.

Comment: What is the exact question?
Assignment operator and copy constructor are two different things.

Comment: Most simple example is if I'm making my own generic linked list, using template<typename DATA> and DATA data; field inside each node. So the question is if in some place on my list code I can use assignment operator between two DATA variables.

Comment: Possibly related: [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: Copy constructor is called only at initialization. Assignment could be done at any time. And you have to take extra care in assignment, not in copy constructor.

Comment: Incidentally, edits and clarifications to the question should probably go into the question body itself, not just in the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment operator and copy constructor and two distinct things though having similar functionality. As for the question that it is considered a bad practice or not, generally it is not a bad idea to do so. The advantage it has is that it can be called from anywhere at almost any time in the program. Copy constructor is usually only invoked at the initialization of an object.

Assignment operator could lead to very dangerous situations sometimes. The programmer is responsible for checking against certain conditions for example self assignment. Here, in case of your linked list, you would also have to destroy the previous list which the object did hold before new assignment.

I hope this was what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> Does using an assignment operator instead of copy c'tor in generic
>   structures, considered as bad coding?

The question is in general terms, so my answer will also be in general terms.

No.  Using an assignment operator is not bad coding in and of itself.  Like anything, it can be misused or implemented incorrectly, but as a concept there is nothing wrong with using assignment operators.  That's what they are there for.

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I'm making my own generic linked list, using template and DATA data; field inside each node. So the question is if in some place on my list code I can use assignment operator between two DATA variables.

In this example, use none of the two, use `swap`. This is faster and exception-safe.

```
using std::swap;
swap(old, new);
```

If you use the assignment operator, first a copy is made and then the destructor is called.

If you use copy constructor, then two destructors and one copy constructor is called.

If you use swap, then one `swap` and one destructor is called. `swap` usually is cheap.